# how to pass a 2 dimention array as an intent extra in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I pass 2d array [][] object as an intent extra to another activity, but its show error i can not be identifies what do i do?

```
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
     SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
     String str = "";  
      if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n"; 

String[][] xmlResponse2= null;
        String[] test = str.split("\n");
        xmlResponse2= new String[0][test.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            xmlResponse2[0][i]=test[i];

        }

     Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
        l.putExtra("msg",xmlResponse2[0][i]);
        l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
            context.startActivity(l);
```

Comment: l.putExtra("msg",xmlResponse2[0][i]);
  this line show an error

Comment: its out of the scope of I you cant use i there

Comment: then how i pass
xmlResponse2[0][i]   value as a parameter to another activity?

Comment: your i is declared in for loop so its scope ends with the for loop cant use it outside

Comment: you need not put xmlResponse2[0][i] just put xmlResponse2

Comment: so how i use intent at which place? so iget Response2[0][i]  this value? inside for loop i used intent???

Comment: no dont use in such a way just pass the whole array like xmlResponse2 and get whatever you wnt @ other side by putting in a loop

Comment: @breceivemail the variable i dont have scope outside for loop as its declared inside that -- thats what i mean