# application not going to intent part

Tags: android

this is my application code below which nto going to intent part i used debug i find is not going after line 
xmlResponse2[0][i]=test[i];
wht i mistake?? can anyone help me is not launch any activity and code broke after 
xmlResponse2[0][i]=test[i];   this line

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";  

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";  



        String[][] xmlResponse2= null;
        String[] test = str.split("\n");
        xmlResponse2= new String[0][test.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            xmlResponse2[0][i]=test[i];
             Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
             l.putExtra("msg",xmlResponse2);
             l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
             context.startActivity(l);
        }

        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: how many times will you start that activity???

Comment: just 1 time after code execute

Comment: now you are putting it in a loop dear that means.......

Comment: Have you mention your activity in AndroidMenifest file

Comment: it seems you are calling the intent in a loop. Are you sure you want it like that? you should avoid such a condition. what is the error you are getting when the code breaks ?

Comment: what is a correct method? plz tell me

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247765/how-to-pass-a-2-dimention-array-as-an-intent-extra-in-android

Comment: @Selvin ofcourse and that too from the same user ;)

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
xmlResponse2= new String[0][test.length];
```

creates an array with 0 elements (ie: with NO elements). Maybe you want to create an array with 1 element, like this:

```
xmlResponse2= new String[1][test.length];
```

Comment: how i start new activity with  using this parameter
l.putExtra("msg",xmlResponse2);

Comment: is this really true? doesn't new String[0][test.length]; actually create these second elements in the first element indexed 0?

Comment: @Carnal i too hope so the index starts from 0 in an array (its a 2 dimensional array that he mean to create after all)

Comment: @Carnal i 2 agree 2 that the index starts from 0 itself i dont get the point why he want it from 1 onwards

Comment: my Application Recievd sms in this format
00    in  line1
LOG   in line2
00 in line 3
Adeel Aslam in line 4

Comment: how i pass this sms format as a parameter to another activity and print

sms is 

00   in line 1
LOg in line 2
00 in line 3
Adeel Aslam in line 4

Comment: @Carnal `new String[0][test.length]` creates a 2-dimensional array that has no elements (because the size of the first dimenstion is zero). It does **not** create an array of `String[test.length]` and assign that to the first element of xmlResponse2! If that is what you want to do you need to do this: `xmlResponse2[0] = new String[test.length]`

Comment: no i want read an sms which is this format
00 in line 1
LOG in line 2
00 in line 3
Adeel Aslam in line 4

Comment: @David Wasser this is not true mate, I just tested and it works fine with new String[0][size];

Comment: Since we are creating 2d array, the last "[]" will decide the size for each array in 2d.

Comment: @Carnal Can't be. Try this: `String[][] foo = new String[0][10]; System.out.println("Size "+foo.length);` You will see that `foo.length` is zero. When you create the array you tell it that the first dimension has zero elements.

Comment: This line `xmlResponse2[0][i]=test[i];` will generate an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with the code as it is.

Comment: @DavidWasser friend an arrays index starts from 0, String[][] foo = new String[0][10]; System.out.println("Size "+foo.length); you are getting 0 as you cannot find the length like that tryfoo[0].length as its two dimenssional

Comment: @droidhot You need to read about how multidimensional arrays work. `foo` in this case is an array of String arrays. Of course you can get its length. In this example`foo[0].length` will also gives you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because as I said in my answer, the variable is an array that contains zero entries. Please buy a Java book and read it before making comments like this.

Comment: @DavidWasser yap it has zero entries as you havent assigned any values but is a[0]="kbhdkha"; valid? dear friend an arrays index start from 0 only ie if an array of length 5 is there then the index is from 0-4 just refer some docs

Comment: @DavidWasser refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 xmlResponse2= new String[test.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        xmlResponse2[i]=test[i];

    }
       Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
         l.putExtra("msg",xmlResponse2);
        // l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
         context.startActivity(l);
```

Comment: my application recieve sms in this format
00
LOG
00
Adeel Aslam

Comment: 00 in line 1
LOG  in line 2
00 in line 3

Comment: soo ??? i dont get what you mean any ways you can send a 2 dimensional array 2 in the same way but by no way inside a loop that feels horible

Comment: no i want read an sms which is this format
00 in line 1
LOG in line 2
00 in line 3